# get value from imported class for interface

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-5

**Setting**

I import a class from my Java project via

```
import myproj.domain.ActionResponse;
```

Then I try to make an interface for a repository with by extending a Neo4jRepository.

I am following these docs:
"parameter types change from `<T>` to `<T, ID>`" - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/

```
@Repository
    public interface ActionResponseRepository extends Neo4jRepository<ActionResponse, ActionResponse.getId() >  {
...
```

ActionResponse extends NamedType which extends GraphType which has a

```
...
@GraphId
    @JsonProperty("id")
    Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
...
```

**Question**

This: 
`extends Neo4jRepository<ActionResponse, ActionResponse.getId() >` is incorrect syntax.

How do I fill the second parameter field with the id from the ActionReponse class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of the annotation is the ID *type*.

So you should declare something like:

```
extends Neo4jRepository<ActionResponse, Long>
```